# storing of db file in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i wanted to know where we should store the db in our project and how can we retrieve the 1st line of the db through the code. Can some one help me through it.

Comment: What do you want to do? Explain it briefly.

Comment: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ try this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Comment: If we want to use the db i the application then what is the procedure to do that????

Comment: db is in your private datafolder the address is yourpackagename/data/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can store DB in SDCARD Or Phone memory.

see this ref [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: If we want to use the db i the application then what is the procedure to do that????

Comment: YOu have already DB? or You want to create new DB?

Comment: hello Rithesh see ref link sample ready there.